# Debugging FTPS SSL validation in Aptana plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, aptana, ftps

I just installed Eclipse with the Aptana plugin. I need to use FTPS to transfer my files to the server, but if I have the 'validate certificate' box checked, I get this error:

> Server Certificate Error: Server certificate could not be validated.
>   (use SSLFTPCertificateException.printCertificates to view
>   certificates.)

I can't find anything in the documentation about how to "use SSLFTPCertificateException.printCertificates"  Can someone point me to where this command needs to be executed? I tried in the terminal and got:

> sh.exe": SSLFTPCertificateException.printCertificates: command not
>   found

Answer (score 2):

If the server is a trusted source you could just uncheck the validate certificate checkbox. You will still connect using FTPS and without the error.